# remove first occurance of an element from a tuple using only functional programming in python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I want to remove only the first occurrence of the element from a tuple in python using only functional programming concepts like map, reduce, filter etc. I am using

```
filter(lambda x: x != E, T)
```

But it removes all the E's from T. I just want to remove first element without using any loops and only map,reduce and filter.

The desired input/output is as follow:

> (0, 1, 2, 1, 3) => (0,2, 1, 3)

thanks

Comment: I don't understand what function you are trying to implement.  You use 'tuple' in the title and 'type' in the text.  Give some input and desired output pairs.

Comment: Added the desired output.

Comment: What version of Python are you doing this in? What exactly are the constraints - are you able to use `range` or `itertools.count` for instance?

Comment: I am using python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @JonClements comment

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> nums = (0, 1, 2, 1, 3)
>>> tuple(filter(lambda x, c=count(): x != 1 or next(c) != 0, nums))
(0, 2, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, takewhile
>>> nums = (0, 1, 2, 1, 3)
>>> i = iter(nums)
>>> tuple(chain(takewhile((1).__ne__, i), i))
(0, 2, 1, 3)
```

On python 2 you'd have to do

```
tuple(chain(takewhile(lambda n: n != 1, i), i))
```

Comment: Won't be particulary efficient on Python 2.x, but the OP's filter could become something like: ... `filter(lambda v, c=iter(range(len(t))): v != 1 or next(c) > 0, t)`  - then you can change the `> 0` as to how many matching values should be present...

Comment: @JonClements I was experimenting with a solution like that, but i wasnt haappy enough with it to post, feel free to if you want. (on py2 they can use `ifilter` of course). EDIT: ok your solution is different to the one i thought of but similar in a way

Comment: I'm not particularly happy with it either as I'm not sure what the OPs constraints are and that was the best I could think of early on a Saturday morning that's *probably* close (and only uses builtins)... hence why just a comment in case you wanted to do something with it :)